# Get User Data in a Formatted Way With Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a requirement to show formatted data in a report. I am using three tables where one adds new users, second one for their payments and the last one for if any user resigns. So here are the sample tables and default data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Entry]
(
    [EmpId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmpName] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [EntryDate] [datetime] NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[Entry] ([EmpId], [EmpName], [Address], [Email], [EntryDate]) 
VALUES (1, N'John', N'On Earth', N'john@abc.com', CAST(0x0000A58000000000 AS DateTime)),
       (2, N'Jack', N'On Earth', N'jack@abc.com', CAST(0x0000A5A800000000 AS DateTime)),
       (3, N'Jessi', N'On Earth', N'jessi@abc.com', CAST(0x0000A5CF00000000 AS DateTime)),
       (4, N'Jackson', N'On Earth', N'jackson@abc.com', CAST(0x0000A5E400000000 AS DateTime))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Payment]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmpId] [int] NULL,
    [Payment] [float] NULL,
    [PayDate] [datetime] NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[Payment] ([Id], [EmpId], [Payment], [PayDate]) 
VALUES (1, 1, 2000, CAST(0x0000A61800000000 AS DateTime)), (2, 1, 2000, CAST(0x0000A63600000000 AS DateTime)),
       (3, 1, 2000, CAST(0x0000A65500000000 AS DateTime)), (4, 1, 2000, CAST(0x0000A67400000000 AS DateTime)),
       (5, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A5DB00000000 AS DateTime)), (6, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A5F900000000 AS DateTime)),
       (7, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A61800000000 AS DateTime)), (8, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A63600000000 AS DateTime)),
       (9, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A65500000000 AS DateTime)), (10, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A67400000000 AS DateTime)),
       (11, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A69200000000 AS DateTime)), (12, 3, 6000, CAST(0x0000A65500000000 AS DateTime)),
       (13, 3, 6000, CAST(0x0000A67400000000 AS DateTime)), (14, 4, 8000, CAST(0x0000A7FF00000000 AS DateTime)),
       (15, 4, 8000, CAST(0x0000A98B00000000 AS DateTime))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Resign]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmpId] [int] NULL,
    [ResignDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Reason] [nchar](10) NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[Resign] ([Id], [EmpId], [ResignDate], [Reason]) 
VALUES (1, 1, CAST(0x0000A69B00000000 AS DateTime), N'Resigned  '),
       (2, 2, CAST(0x0000A6C400000000 AS DateTime), N'Resigned')
```

The required output is as follows that'll be year-wise:

```
Year 2015

Month - Jan - Feb - Mar - Apr - May - Jun - Jul - Aug - Sep - Oct - Nov - Dec
Opening - 10 - 10 - 10 - 12 - 12 - 12 - 12 - 12 - 12 - 12 - 8 - 8 //Total no. of employee
Add     -  0 -  0 -  2 -  0 -  0 -  0 -  0 -  0 -  0 -  0 - 0 - 0 //Newly added
Left    -  0 -  0 -  0 -  0 -  0 -  0 -  0 -  0 -  0 -  4 - 0 - 0 //Resigned
Closing - 10 - 10 - 12 - 12 - 12 - 12 - 12 - 12 - 12 -  8 - 8 - 8 //Closing Total

Year 2016

Month - Jan - Feb - Mar - Apr - May - Jun - Jul - Aug - Sep - Oct - Nov - Dec
Opening - 8 ----Goes on in the similar way
Add -----
Left ----
Closing ----
```

So this is clear how the data should be shown in the report. Though I am aware of the grouping year-wise in the report and have tried similar to show the data month-wise as follows:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(YYYY, Q.PayDate) [YEAR], 
    COUNT(m.EmpId) Total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, m.EntryDate) = 'January' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [JAN],
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATENAME(MONTH, m.EntryDate) = 'February' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [FEB]  
FROM 
    Entry m 
INNER JOIN 
    Payment q ON Q.EmpId = M.EmpId 
LEFT JOIN
    Resign OUT ON OUT.EmpId = m.EmpId 
WHERE 
    m.EmpId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT p.EmpId FROM Resign p)
    AND m.EmpId IN (SELECT DISTINCT k.EmpId FROM Payment k)
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(YYYY, Q.PayDate), DATEPART(MM, m.EntryDate);
```

The above query returns something as follows:

```
YEAR  Total JAN FEB
--------------------
2016  2     0   0
2017  1     0   0
2018  1     0   0
```

But I am not sure how can I show the newly added as well resigned users with the opening in the same query row-wise as the sample given?

**N.B**: I am open to any query languages. So expecting your ideas to implement it in an appropriate way.

Comment: "But I am not sure how can I show the newly added as well resigned users with the opening in the same query row-wise as the sample given?" I think you need a dynamic pivot SQL query "generator" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: Looks like you could schedule eve this with some grouping and a matrix. I'll try and get some time to explain this.

Comment: Achieve* silly autocorrect...

Comment: How is the opening value calculated? Once I know this I should be able to come up with a solution fairly easily

Comment: The opening is calculated with the total no. of added users in the system yearly @Alan Schofield. So you can say the total no. of users in the system as opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely shift your effort over to a reporting tool such as SSRS if you plan to run many of these. It will simplify things many times over. That being said, here is one way that would produce the results you mentioned above.

```
DECLARE @Entry TABLE
(
    [EmpId] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [EmpName] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [EntryDate] [datetime] NULL
)

INSERT @Entry ([EmpId], [EmpName], [Address], [Email], [EntryDate]) 

VALUES
       (100, N'Early', N'On Earth', N'john@abc.com', '01/01/2015'),
       (1, N'John', N'On Earth', N'john@abc.com', CAST(0x0000A58000000000 AS DateTime)),
       (2, N'Jack', N'On Earth', N'jack@abc.com', CAST(0x0000A5A800000000 AS DateTime)),
       (3, N'Jessi', N'On Earth', N'jessi@abc.com', CAST(0x0000A5CF00000000 AS DateTime)),
       (4, N'Jackson', N'On Earth', N'jackson@abc.com', CAST(0x0000A5E400000000 AS DateTime))

DECLARE @Payment TABLE 
(
    [Id] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [EmpId] [int] NULL,
    [Payment] [float] NULL,
    [PayDate] [datetime] NULL
)

INSERT @Payment ([Id], [EmpId], [Payment], [PayDate]) 
VALUES (1, 1, 2000, CAST(0x0000A61800000000 AS DateTime)), (2, 1, 2000, CAST(0x0000A63600000000 AS DateTime)),
       (3, 1, 2000, CAST(0x0000A65500000000 AS DateTime)), (4, 1, 2000, CAST(0x0000A67400000000 AS DateTime)),
       (5, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A5DB00000000 AS DateTime)), (6, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A5F900000000 AS DateTime)),
       (7, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A61800000000 AS DateTime)), (8, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A63600000000 AS DateTime)),
       (9, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A65500000000 AS DateTime)), (10, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A67400000000 AS DateTime)),
       (11, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A69200000000 AS DateTime)), (12, 3, 6000, CAST(0x0000A65500000000 AS DateTime)),
       (13, 3, 6000, CAST(0x0000A67400000000 AS DateTime)), (14, 4, 8000, CAST(0x0000A7FF00000000 AS DateTime)),
       (15, 4, 8000, CAST(0x0000A98B00000000 AS DateTime))

DECLARE  @Resign TABLE
(
    [Id] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [EmpId] [int] NULL,
    [ResignDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Reason] [nchar](10) NULL
)

INSERT @Resign ([Id], [EmpId], [ResignDate], [Reason]) 
VALUES (1, 1, CAST(0x0000A69B00000000 AS DateTime), N'Resigned  '),
       (2, 2, CAST(0x0000A6C400000000 AS DateTime), N'Resigned')

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '01/01/2015'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '12/01/2016'

;WITH Calendar as
 (
    SELECT CalendarDate = @StartDate, CalendarYear = DATEPART(YEAR, @StartDate), CalendarMonth = DATEPART(MONTH, @StartDate)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CalendarDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CalendarDate),  CalendarYear = DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate), CalendarMonth = DATEPART(MONTH, CalendarDate)
    FROM Calendar
    WHERE DATEADD (MONTH, 1, CalendarDate) <= @EndDate
 )
 ,Employees AS
 (
     SELECT
        E.EmpID,
        StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, EntryDate), 0),
        EndDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, ResignDate), 0)
    FROM     
        @Entry E
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @Resign R ON R.EmpId = E.EmpId
)
,NormalizedAndUnpivoted AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        CalendarMonth = DATEPART(MONTH,CalendarDate),
        CalendarYear = DATEPART(YEAR,CalendarDate),
        GroupField = CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,CalendarDate) AS NVARCHAR(50))+'_'+CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,CalendarDate) AS NVARCHAR(50)),
        SortOrder = CASE 
            WHEN Property='Opening' THEN 1
            WHEN Property='Addition'  THEN 2
            WHEN Property='Subtraction'  THEN 3
            WHEN Property='Total'  THEN 4
        END
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            C.CalendarDate,
            Opening =  COUNT(DISTINCT EmpExisting.EmpID) ,
            Addition = COUNT(DISTINCT EmpStarted.EmpID),
            Subtraction = COUNT(DISTINCT EmpEnd.EmpID),
            Total = COUNT(DISTINCT EmpExisting.EmpID) + COUNT(DISTINCT EmpStarted.EmpID) - COUNT(DISTINCT EmpEnd.EmpID)
        FROM 
            Calendar C
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees EmpExisting ON EmpExisting.StartDate < C.CalendarDate AND (EmpExisting.EndDate IS NULL OR EmpExisting.EndDate >=  C.CalendarDate)
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees EmpStarted ON EmpStarted.StartDate = C.CalendarDate
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees EmpEnd ON EmpEnd.EndDate = C.CalendarDate
        GROUP BY
            C.CalendarDate      
    )AS X
    UNPIVOT(
        PivotValue FOR Property IN (Opening, Addition, Subtraction, Total)
    ) AS U
)
,Pivoted AS
(
    SELECT
        CalendarYear,
        Property,
        SortOrder,
        Janurary=SUM(CASE WHEN CalendarMonth=1 THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END),
        Feburary=SUM(CASE WHEN CalendarMonth=2 THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END),
        March=SUM(CASE WHEN CalendarMonth=3 THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END),
        April=SUM(CASE WHEN CalendarMonth=4 THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END),
        May=SUM(CASE WHEN CalendarMonth=5 THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END),
        June=SUM(CASE WHEN CalendarMonth=6 THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END),
        July=SUM(CASE WHEN CalendarMonth=7 THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END),
        August=SUM(CASE WHEN CalendarMonth=8 THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END),
        September=SUM(CASE WHEN CalendarMonth=9 THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END),
        October=SUM(CASE WHEN CalendarMonth=10 THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END),
        November=SUM(CASE WHEN CalendarMonth=11 THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END),
        December=SUM(CASE WHEN CalendarMonth=12 THEN PivotValue ELSE NULL END)
    FROM
        NormalizedAndUnpivoted
    GROUP BY
        CalendarYear,
        Property,
        SortOrder
)

SELECT * FROM Pivoted
ORDER BY
    CalendarYear,
    SortOrder
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Results:

```
CalendarYear Property                       SortOrder   Janurary    Feburary    March       April       May         June        July        August      September   October     November    December
------------ ------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2015         Opening                        1           0           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1
2015         Addition                       2           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2015         Subtraction                    3           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2015         Total                          4           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1           1
2016         Opening                        1           1           2           3           4           5           5           5           5           5           5           4           3
2016         Addition                       2           1           1           1           1           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0
2016         Subtraction                    3           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           1           1           0
2016         Total                          4           2           3           4           5           5           5           5           5           5           4           3           3
```

Comment: This worked perfectly @Ross Bush. As you have written about to shift in reporting tool, assume I'll be using `Crystal Report`. So how or is it possible to make it bit easier like creating a view and get it work with?

Comment: Glad you found it useful. SQL is not very useful for creating reports. That is why reporting toolsets have been created overtime. I would generally pull detailed data from a stored procedure that returned all needed fields and joined the three tables for this report....Let the reporting tool do all the unfolding,folding,totaling etc. If this satisfied your question then please mark as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle solution. In second line put report year.

- `mc` counts new and resigning persons per months
- `t` is hierarchical subquery counting `opening` and `closing` values for each month. First part, anchor, counts entries in tables `entry` and `resign` for older years, this is our starting point. To this anchor we attach values month by month searching them in `mc`
- last step is `pivot` and ordering, added here only to present data as you requested.

Query:

```
with 
  y as (select 2016 yr from dual),
  mc as (   
    select mm, sum(a) a, sum(c) c
      from ( select extract (month from entrydate) mm, 1 a, 0 c
               from entry, y where extract(year from entrydate) = yr
             union all
             select extract (month from resigndate) mm, 0 a, 1 c
               from resign, y where extract(year from resigndate) = yr) 
      group by mm ),
  t(mm, o, a, r, c) as (
    select 0, 0, 0, 0, 
           ( (select count(1) from entry where extract(year from entrydate) < yr)
           - (select count(1) from resign where extract(year from resigndate) < yr) ) 
      from y
    union all
    select t.mm + 1, t.c, mc.a, mc.c, t.c + nvl(mc.a, 0) - nvl(mc.c, 0)
      from t left join mc on mc.mm = t.mm + 1 
      where t.mm + 1 <= 12)
select * 
    from (
        select * from t
            unpivot (cnt for type in (o, a, r, c)))
    pivot (sum(cnt) for mm in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))
    order by case type when 'O' then 1 when 'A' then 2 
                       when 'R' then 3 when 'C' then 4 
             end
```

Result for provided data and year 2016:

```
TYPE      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12
---- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
O         0      1      2      3      4      4      4      4      4      4      3      2
A         1      1      1      1                                         0      0 
R         0      0      0      0                                         1      1 
C         1      2      3      4      4      4      4      4      4      3      2      2
```

It's mostly standard SQL, you may need change functions like `extract` to their SQLServer equivalent. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your query @Ponder Stibbons. Unfortunately got a compilation error at the beginning WITH statement. Is it possible to turn into a view or stored procedure, so easier to show in a report rather reporting tools with `Oracle 10g`?